# How to transform data with Python's sklearn.discriminant_analysis.LinearDiscriminantAnalysis

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I am using `sklearn`'s `discriminant_analysis.LinearDiscriminantAnalysis` class, and I see that there is a `transform` function, but I don't see how to learn the transformation based on training data and then apply that transformation in future predictions.

I'm looking at the documentation at http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.discriminant_analysis.LinearDiscriminantAnalysis.html#sklearn.discriminant_analysis.LinearDiscriminantAnalysis.transform

```
model.transform(X)
```

It appears that this function just transforms the data to maximize its separation, and it returns the transformed data.

Comment: Do you mean: Given training data, learn the class separation (via a classifier) and make predictions on future data, using the learned classifier?

Comment: @ilanman : I don't think so. For that I would use `fit` and then `predict`. What is not clear is how `transform` can be learned from one dataset then applied to another.

Comment: why doesn't `fit_transform` solve your problem?

Comment: @ilanman : That fits a transformer to `X`, then returns a model, but the model doesn't include the transformer, does it? The next set of data examples cannot receive the same transformation as `X` did, it appears. Or am I reading the documentation incorrectly?